# Encoding with php call R

Tags: php, r, cmd

I have problems on using php call R words encoding
(My environment is win7 + PHP 5.2.6 + R 2.14)

I used above php code to generate a plot png on html:

```
putenv('PATH="D:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin"');

// R CMD BATCH
//echo system('R CMD BATCH --vanilla "E:\AppServ\www\BILOG\test.R"');
// Rscript source
//echo system('Rscript -e \'source("E:\AppServ\www\BILOG\test.R")\'');
// Rscript --vanilla
//echo system('Rscript --vanilla "E:\AppServ\www\BILOG\test.R"');
```

And my test.R (generate simple plot with Chinese title,  "測試" means test)

```
setwd('C:/')
png(file = 'output.png')
x=c(1.82117,1.50794,1.66560,1.16217);
hist(x, nclass=8, main="測試");
dev.off()
q()
```

I use 3 ways with php function system() call R

1. R CMD BATCH
2. Rscript source
3. Rscript --vanilla

Finally the output.png can't display chinese words  "測試"
(I tried use php file in utf-8 and ansi, but no use, and my R script is ansi)

If i used win7's cmd execute R CMD BATCH --vanilla "E:\AppServ\www\BILOG\test.R"
(and used R-gui, it succeeded, but R script should be ansi)

it succeeded, can display "測試", and used php can't display "測試".

Could someone solve this problems about encoding!? I would appreciate.